# Set Maximum leave employee 3 tables

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have 3 tables looked like this

```
Employee Table
id | EmpId | Name |    
1  |  N1   |  A   |
2  |  N2   |  B   |
3  |  N3   |  C   |

Leave Table
id | EmpId | applydate  | startdate  | daysleave | reason   | status   |
1  |  N2   | 2016-08-25 | 2016-08-25 |     4     | vacation | Approved |

Setting Table
id |   var    | val | valdef | status |
1  | MaxLeave | 12  |   12   |    1   |
```

Each employee has max leave 12 days taken from Setting Table.
If daysleave = 4,then maxleave it should be 8 days left.
how did i do that ?should i add new field on Employee Table ?
Result Expected :
[image: Result Expected]

Comment: Means you want to show how many days left for the employee?? Please give expected result set if possible

Comment: yes,i will make one

Comment: What if an employee has multiple records in the Leave table? Or is only one record shown in the UI?

Comment: it is only 1 record in the UI,but it's possible if one employee has multiple records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create get function in model to retrieve information you need example:

```
    public function getDaysOfLeaveLeft() {
        // query for the data you need and return days left
        return $days; 
    }
```

Then in view you display it

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'daysOfLeaveLeft',
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

**EDIT**

Full function

```
public function getDaysOfLeaveLeft() {
            $models = LeaveTable::findAll(['EmpId' => $this->EmpId]);
            $leave = 0;
            foreach ($models as $model) {
                $leave += $model->daysleave;
            }
            $setting = Setting::find(['var' => 'MaxLeave']);
            return $setting->val - $leave;
        }
```

Comment: field daysOfLeaveLeft is still does not exist yet.i haven't create a function that count MaxLeave - daysLeave = daysOfLeaveLeft .

Comment: Did you create function in model you feed to DetailView?

Comment: i havent.do i need to join 3 table first ?

Comment: when 3 table joined,it will shows this ,id | EmpId | applydate  | startdate  | daysleave | val |

Comment: You add function and in this function you query for days of leave left. You retrieve all records from leave table for given employee, sum daysleave of all of those records, subtract it from max leave and return this value.

Comment: if i already make some query,where do i display it in here ? so you can correct me if i wrong ?

Comment: the code works,thank you,i edited Setting::find because it doesnt have a model